# Create / load the typescript source file, such that it is listed in programs source files

Tags: typescript

I need to create references to external files (which are originally not part of a program). I want to get them as TypeScript SourceFiles, so I can create references to them.

I need to create/load the external source file, such that, when I try getting it's `program.getSourceFile(fileName)`, it results in a real file.

Is there a way? I tried:

- Creating source files using `ts.createLanguageServiceSourceFile`
- Creating source files using `ts.createSourceFile`
- Passing files in `getExternalFiles` of my plugin

Answer (score 0):

I used `project.addMissingFileRoot(file)`!